# Printing values and alignment C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to print a bill sheet.

The list of all invoice is obtained by this command into a listbox.

```
con.Open();                
            MySqlCommand command1 = con.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            command1.CommandText = "SELECT service,price FROM `order` WHERE billno='" + label15.Text + "' AND dates=DATE(NOW())";
            Reader = command1.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                string thisrow = "";                    
                for (int k = 0; k < Reader.FieldCount; k++)                        
                    thisrow += Reader.GetValue(k).ToString() +"".PadRight(10);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(thisrow);                    
            }
            con.Close();
```

now i wish to print them using this code

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
            {                    
                string Service = item;                                      
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Service, new Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 10 + offset);
                    offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
                }
            }
```

the printing happens but the alignments of all the prices are wrong.
[image]

Comment: What UI framework are you using? Is this a web or Windows app? In order to guarantee accurate formatting, have you considered generating a pdf document, that your users then print? Also, you should consider parameterising your SQL query to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Does this UI technology have any kind of table layout you can use?  That seems appropriate for this kind of data.

Comment: @RichardEverett this is windows form application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this method.

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
        {                   
            string service = item.Substring(0,item.Length-3);
            string price = item.Substring(item.Length - 3, 3);
            {

                e.Graphics.DrawString(service, new Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 10 + offset);
                e.Graphics.DrawString("".PadRight(14)+price, new Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 10 + offset);
                offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
            }
        }
```

Comment: one of the overloads od DrawString take a StringFormat argument, you can use it to speficy right alignment
Also note that you are creating new fonts and brushes at every iteration, and don't dispose them as you should

Answer (score 0):

The alignments are wrong is because of `.PadRight(10)`.
`"GROOM (M)"` and `"Style (M)"` both have 9 chars where `"WAX (M)"` has 7 chars. That could be the reason, why the numbers 8 and 6 have a wrong alignment.

Comment: I know that... can you provide me with a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the immediate problem you might consider making your `service` string a predictable length, perhaps using `String.PadRight()`, e.g. `item.PadRight(16);` to force it to a length of 16 characters. Then append the price and you'll have your offset.

This is a bit of a hack, though. You're using Windows Forms, which has a [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) for nice tablular layouts. Or, if you're intending to print this information, consider outputting to a predictable format like XPS or PDF.

Also pay heed to the other suggestions on how to improve your code with [parameterized SQL queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "courier new" font, that each characters have a same size.
make sure your service list have maximal character. e.g. 10 so you can using padleft or padright

```
your_string.PadLeft(10, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about exact values you can receive, but I will suppose that your input is of style `item (M) price`. So instead of using `PadRight(10)` why not insert spaces inside yourself?
Let´s say you will drop that padding and build only a simple string . So you will get something like `WAX (M) 15`. That is 10 characters. This can be achieved with your original code with only a minor modification from :

```
thisrow += Reader.GetValue(k).ToString() +"".PadRight(10);
```

to this:

```
thisrow += Reader.GetValue(k).ToString();
```

Then I would look for last space and append enough additional spaces to make appropriate length of a line. So go from your original line

```
string Service = item;
```

to something like:

```
int billLineLength = 20;
string service = item;

int missingSpaces = billLineLength - service.Length;

if(missingSpaces > 0) {
    string filler = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < missingSpaces; i++) {
        filler += " ";
    }
    service = service.Insert(service.LastIndexOf(' '), filler);
}
```

Through, you will have to experiment with a `billLineLenght` a little bit to fit nicely into your expected output.

I hope that it will help you.

---

As a side note, I would recommend you to stop naming your variables with capital letters since `Reader.FieldCount` really looks like you are using a property of a static class, while it is actually a variable. This helps to clarify your code for any reader.

Comment: It works for first two values not for wax... can i do this using dataGridview? instead of listbox? if yes please guide me...

Comment: Uhm, can you please explain in a more detail what does not work? Is the line short, long, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you didn't like my previous idea, so I will try another solution. This one does not give you so much grip on the process, but could suit you since it is simpler. 
And I am not editing original answer because it stands and this one offers different approach.

I suppose that you would like to have prices aligned to right and preceded with spaces. Your problem is, that your code

```
thisrow += Reader.GetValue(k).ToString() +"".PadRight(10);
```

takes value from reader (`Reader.GetValue(k)`), converts it to string (`.ToString()`) and then appends empty string (`""`) padded with spaces *on right* so its total length is 10 (`"".PadRight(10)` changes to `"          "` - ten spaces) and then appends all this to your variable `thisrow`. 
What you probably seek is `PadLeft` which adds spaces to *left* side and it should be executed on received and converted value. I.E.:

```
thisrow += Reader.GetValue(k).ToString().PadLeft(10);
```